# How to add margin just for non-edge items in flex

Tags: css, flexbox

Is it possible to have a margin defined for items within a flex container that are not on the edge? For example, I want my first and last items in a row to have zero margin so that it's flush w/ the edge of the container, but any items in between to have left and right margins. I can't do `:first-child` or `:last-child` b/c the `:last-child` may be on another row if I shrink the window size, which will force the items to wrap to the next rows.

Css:

```
.parent {
  display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap; background:gray;
}

.item {
  flex: 1 1 100px; background: white; margin: 10px;
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="item">
    hello
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    world
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    flex
  </div>
</div>
```

Jsbin: http://jsbin.com/hidife/1/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with negative margins:

Change this:

```
.parent {
  display:flex; 
  flex-wrap:wrap; 
  background:gray;
}

.item {
  flex: 1 1 100px; 
  background: white; 
  margin: 10px;
}
```

To this:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  display: flex; 
  flex-wrap: wrap; 
  background: gray;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.item {
  flex: 1 1 100px;
  background: white; 
  margin: 10px 0 10px 10px;
}
```

Relevant HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="item">
    hello
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    world
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    flex
  </div>
</div>
```

bin: http://jsbin.com/jegopejaze/1/